# How do I get Views working with CiviCRM and Backdrop?

Tags: drupal-views, backdrop

I followed the instructions for getting Views working with Drupal but it's not working in Backdrop. I see:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.civicrm_contact' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting Views working with Backdrop is essentially the same as getting Views working with Drupal, although there can be one extra step. So first, [follow these instructions to get CiviCRM's tables into Views](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/2181/26).

Regarding the possible second step, Backdrop by default uses a simplified structure to specify database credentials ([more](https://api.backdropcms.org/database-configuration)). This will not cause a problem if you are using the same database for CiviCRM and Backdrop and you do not have a second step.

If, however, you have CiviCRM in a separate database, you need to adjust your Backdrop settings.php in one additional way, changing the default/simplified database string...

```
$database = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/database_name';
```

...to allow multiple databases:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'database_name',
  'username' => 'user',
  'password' => 'pass',
  'host' => 'localhost',
);
```

@colemanw's note from the Drupal answer applies here, too: "if your [Backdrop] sql user and CiviCRM sql user are different then you need to grant SELECT privileges to the [Backdrop] one for the CiviCRM db."

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment on the other answer (I don't have enough reputation), but here are some additional information suggestions:

https://forum.backdropcms.org/forum/backdropcms-views-and-civicrm-integration

I got it working with these two changes:

1. We made this change:

```
OLD:    $database_prefix = array(
NEW:    $databases['default']['default']['prefix']= array(
```

2. We removed the backticks on all the table items we had pasted into the settings.php file:

```
OLD:    'civicrm_view_case_activity_recent'        => '`tcog2_civicrm`.',
NEW:    'civicrm_view_case_activity_recent'        => 'tcog2_civicrm.',
```

Comment: Can you paste the relevant bits into your answer directly?

Comment: Added additional details. Thanks for suggestion.