# Baffled by Views database error on new install

Tags: permissions, drupal-views, mysql, backdrop

Hours-old install of CiviCRM 5.25 under Backdrop 1.9. I've gotten as far as putting in the Board of Directors with dummy bio information, which I was trying to use to generate a View with a page display of names and bios. I get this, with various permutations of what table doesn't exist depending on what I'm doing:

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'B1.civicrm_uf_match' doesn't exist`

Both Backdrop and CiviCRM are using the same mysql user "B1", who has GRANT ALL permissions on the B1 and C5 tables. Obviously, the data is still there when I go back to review it in the Civi interface. What to check next?

Comment: Not sure it makes any difference to the question at hand, but any particular reason you're using Backdrop 1.9?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I must've flashed back to a previous install. 1.15.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it. First, start with Pradeep's answer and Laryn's in the comments.

There's a bug in the output text from Administer >> System Settings >> CMS Integration. It starts the block of text with `$database_prefix = array(` but it still needs the code as listed in the documentation (in an uncopyable screenshot): `$databases['default']['default']['prefix'] = array(`.

Note for those confused if they reused the same name for the database and the user: with databases/users named Backdrop and CiviCRM, "Backdrop" goes under user in the code described by Laryn, but CiviCRM shows up as the prefix in the code copied out of CMS Integration. Aside from the initial line, the rest works as expected.

Comment: have you reported this bug? https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting

Comment: I hadn't, and I'm willing to, but reading that list of steps makes it almost as difficult as fixing my problem in the first place

Comment: sorry to hear that. but reporting bugs is a key task in helping this community driven free open source project improve

Comment: if you can offer suggestions on what can be improved on those instructions i will pass it on

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Submitted

Comment: Well done Jeff - would be great if you could close the loop by putting a link in your Answer

Answer (score 3):

Try adding cms integration in your backdrop settings.php

CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> CMS Integration.

Step by step documentation : https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/backdrop/views/

Comment: I am following the documentation but the code examples do not match the output from the CMS Integration screen, and I don't have the PHP fu to figure out what to patch?

Comment: The code in the documentation screenshot is just an example.  Copy and paste the settings for your system exactly as is from the CMS Integration page.

Comment: Pay special attention to step 9 in the docs, also described here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21085/how-do-i-get-views-working-with-civicrm-and-backdrop

Comment: @aidan The code in the documentation is a screenshot, we confused folks have no choice but to get the code from the CMS integration page. What I meant earlier is that the data structure in the CMS integration output does not match what the docs say it will be. Going back to try again....